# CSS Hover on Elements with Transformation [Chrome/Webkit Bug]

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I have a div I'm applying a transform to with CSS. The actual transformation is as follows:

```
.trans{
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -30deg) translateZ(1px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -30deg) translateZ(150px);
}
```

The problem as far as I've been able to find out is that this rotates the div 'behind' the page in depth. It shows up correctly, but doesn't seem to interact with the mouse correctly. So my CSS class for the hover state doesn't work at all on these elements.

You can check out the [reduced testcase](http://jsfiddle.net/njMyG/). In the result pane, note that the square on the left does not change background colors correctly but the square on the right does. This bug happens on Chrome, but not on Firefox or IE when I tested.

Any good ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to declare a `display` property for `.trans` class for it to work. Thats it.

Here is the [Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/njMyG/4/).

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="square trans">
    <p>Text Here!</p>
</div>
<div class="square">
    <p>Text Here!</p>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.square{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #222222;
    border width: 6px;
    border-style: dotted;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.trans{
    transform-origin: right center;
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -30deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -30deg);
    display:table-cell;

}

/* Doesn't work on transformed square! */
.square:hover{
     background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, that does seem to make it work, although in my actual use case which would be too long to post here, it didn't work, so I'll look for why that is. Curiously, what does adding that do to fix the problem?

Comment: You can send a link by uploading it. - @user1103976

Comment: Here's something more similar to what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/2scc3/1/  With this one, it's the squares on either side that have the problem.

I apologize for the horrible CSS, have no real experience and am making it up as I go ha ha

Comment: Here you go. Find the working solution http://jsfiddle.net/2scc3/2/ works on chrome perfectly. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work well. Have any explanation to why what you did works, or do you just attribute it as a workaround to a bug?

Comment: Well I just added `position` to the `div`. Thats it. Just applied routine CSS properties without working or looking for any workarounds or hacks. So I just sticked to the basics and things worked. Hope explanation is justified :) - @user1103976